# How to press default softkey using android espresso?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-espresso, searchview

I need to fire search when the user press the default soft key button after filling `SearchView`.

How do i simulate user pressing default soft key?

**Update**
As required, my code.

The xml definition of the SearchText:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        style="@style/AppTheme.SearchBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
```

The code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_box))
            .perform(typeSearchViewText("whatever query"),pressImeActionButton())
```

Note: [`typeSearchViewText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037073/2700303) is my implementation of `typeText` for `SearchViews`

Answer (score 1):

You can use espresso viewaction method [pressImeActionButton()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#pressImeActionButton())

Comment: Passing  as parameter of the perform method i get the generic error 'Error performing ...'. Calling from outside, just keep waiting for something.

Comment: I tested on a TextView and worked. i think it need to be extended to support SearchView too.

Comment: @ByteArtisan Share the code you are using in question