# How to type text on a SearchView using espresso

Tags: android, searchview, android-espresso

`TypeText` doesn't seem to work with `SearchView`.

```
onView(withId(R.id.yt_search_box))
            .perform(typeText("how is the weather?"));
```

gives the error:

> Error performing 'type text(how is the weather?)' on view 'with id:../yt_search_box'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For anyone that bump into this problem too, the solution is to write a ViewAction for the type SearchView, since the typeText only supports TextEditView

Here my solution:

```
public static ViewAction typeSearchViewText(final String text){
    return new ViewAction(){
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            //Ensure that only apply if it is a SearchView and if it is visible.
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(SearchView.class));
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Change view text";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            ((SearchView) view).setQuery(text,false);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, however the text are not visible in the SearchView text box, but the query is fired. At least you gave me an automated way to test SearchView.  Thank you.

Comment: If you want to trigger search, change to setQuery(text, true);

Answer (score 10):

@MiguelSlv answer above, converted to kotlin

```
fun typeSearchViewText(text: String): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Change view text"
        }

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(SearchView::class.java))
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
            (view as SearchView).setQuery(text, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("how is the weather?"))
```

Comment: You should give next time more explanations why your solution is supposed to work. At first sight I thought it's the same code like in the question but it's not :D. The secret key is the ID used R.id.search_src_text which access the view that is opened by clicking your own view.

Comment: You could also use `withId(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)` for the ID, to give clarity of where that ID comes from.

Comment: @NenaSchmidt It was hard to remember the context of my answer, but I finally remember. The key difference is the `id` of the component. I dug deep into the component and found one that works.

Comment: Is the internal id not subject not change? This seems like a bad answer.

Comment: You should probably add that Google has example test code that uses this because it seems very hacky to rely on internal implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

Based on César Noreña respose I manage to insert text in the search field.
First I clicked on my view and then typeText on the android search view id.

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_own_search_menu_id)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("how is the weather?"))
```

Also the X button of SearchView has ID search_close_btn

```
onView(withId(R.id.search_close_btn)).perform(click()); // first time erase the content
onView(withId(R.id.search_close_btn)).perform(click()); // second time close the SearchView
```

Comment: Is the internal id not subject not change? This seems like a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Resource#getSystem to get the View

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
    "id", "android")


onView(withId(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
"id", "android"))).perform(clearText(),typeText("enter the text"))
.perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```

Answer (score 0):

To type text in the search view in toolbar you can use the following code in your tests

```
onView(
        withId(R.id.search)
    ).perform(click())
//This is the id of the search icon

onView(
        instanceOf(SearchAutoComplete::class.java)
    ).perform(typeText("abc"))
```

This will type the text in the Searchview in toolbar

Comment: And what happens if you have two SearchAutoComplete in your app?